# Does Ethereum JSON-RPC have rate limits

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I am currently using a public RPC URL to interact with smart contracts on a Ethereum-forked blockchain. I would like to understand if there are any limitations (eg. rate limits) when interacting with a smart contract.

```js
const tokenContract = new WEB3_RPC_CLIENT.eth.Contract(token.abi, token.tokenAddress);
const result = await tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(ethAddress).call();
const format = WEB3_RPC_CLIENT.utils.fromWei(result, token.decimals);
```

Given the example above, which lines might trigger a rate limit - if they even have any limitations at all?

Or is it that methods only counts towards some rate limit protection if they incur a (gas fee) cost?

Comment: Rate limits with the RPC provider you mean?

Comment: @pguardiario Yes

Comment: I imagine they all have different rate limits, I believe infura is 100k per day

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to understand if there are any limitations (eg. rate limits) when interacting with a smart contract.

[Run your own Ethereum node and there are no rate limits, or you can set them yourself](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513). If you are using a commercial node provider then any rate limit question is a commercial support question and out of scope for StackOverflow.